# card view and layout in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i am trying to accomplish layout where components are overlay in flutter but im having problem.

here is the code that i have so far

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FirstFragment extends StatelessWidget {

  _getSizes() {
  }

  _getPositions(){
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Container(
    constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(
    height: 200.0,
    ),
    padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 16.0),
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    child: new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      children: [
        Text(
          '0.00',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 50.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold

          ),
        ),
        Text(
          'Current Balance',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 26.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          ),
        ),
      new Card(
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Image.network('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fq4N0hgOWzU/maxresdefault.jpg'),
            new Padding(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                child: new Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Padding(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                      child: new Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                    ),
                    new Padding(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                      child: new Text('Like',style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                    ),
                    new Padding(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                      child: new Icon(Icons.comment),
                    ),
                    new Padding(
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                      child: new Text('Comments',style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                    )

                  ],
                )
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
      ],
    )

    );
  }

}
```

when you run the code, you will notice that the card view shrink and doesnt overlay the container.  i am looking to do the same as the image below:
[image]

notice how the card view with title of Summary is overlay the blue background and then there are other card views below summary card view.

i am getting the following from my code. the card view doesnt overlay like the image above.  can someone help?  thanks in advance

NOTE: it will be great if anyone can make my card view look like the one in Summary card view in the image above. the one in my code i copied from somewebiste with the goal of making it look like the image above

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove following from your `Container`

```
constraints: new BoxConstraints.expand(
  height: 200.0,
)
```

Add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to your `Column`.

```
new Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // add this
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: ...
)
```

---

Full solution:

```
class FirstFragment extends StatelessWidget {
  _getSizes() {}

  _getPositions() {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 16.0),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
      child: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text(
            '0.00',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 50.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          Text(
            'Current Balance',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 26.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          new Card(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new Image.network('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fq4N0hgOWzU/maxresdefault.jpg'),
                new Padding(
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                    child: new Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Padding(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                          child: new Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                          child: new Text(
                            'Like',
                            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                          child: new Icon(Icons.comment),
                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                          child: new Text('Comments', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                        )
                      ],
                    ))
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution CopsOnRoad. however, the card view is not overlay over the blue background.  the card view is inside the blue color.  look at the first picture above.  the Summary card view is between the blue background and the white.  i would like to do the same.

Comment: OK, got it you need to use `Stack` for this.